How do I get Supervisor Email from an Employee List with Employee Email in PowerBI?
I have a dataset with Employee Number, Employee Name, Employee Email, and Employee Supervisor. The Supervisors are also listed on the Employee List and have emails on their line item. I'm hoping to use this to get a column for Supervisor Email in PoewrBI, preferably Power Query, but DAX will work.
I can't modify supervisor name to get supervisor email because some emails are in a different format, it would have to come from the existing email column tied to their employee record.
enter image description here
This needs to happen for 500+ employees, so can't be done on an individual basis
Lookup Value in DAX
Merging Columns

In Power Query you could Merge the table on itself, then expand to get the Supervisor Email.
Have a look at Merge queries overview.


I have a dataset with Employee Number, Employee Name, Employee Email,
and Employee Supervisor.

Use PowerQuery.
Employees table (don't load):
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\PowerBI\Employee Supervisors.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Employee Number", Int64.Type}, {"Employee Name", type text}, {"Email", type text}, {"Supervisor", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

Supervisors table:
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\PowerBI\Employee Supervisors.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Employee Number", Int64.Type}, {"Employee Name", type text}, {"Email", type text}, {"Supervisor", type text}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Supervisor"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Supervisor"}, Employees, {"Employee Name"}, "Employees", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded Employees" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Employees", {"Employee Number", "Email"}, {"Employee Number", "Email"})
in
    #"Expanded Employees"

Then you basically merge those, and Bob's your Uncle, you're finished. Like this:
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Employees, {"Supervisor"}, Supervisors, {"Supervisor"}, "Supervisors", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Supervisors" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Supervisors", {"Email"}, {"Email.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Supervisors",{{"Email.1", "Supervisor EMail"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"

You end up with this:
Employee Number Employee Name   Email   Supervisor  Supervisor EMail
111111  John Doe    johndoe@company.com Jane Smith  janesmith@company.com
222222  Jane Smith  janesmith@company.com   Torple Scott    torplescott@company.com
333333  Trundle Bed trundlebed@company.com  Torple Scott    torplescott@company.com
444444  Torple Scott    torplescott@company.com John Doe    johndoe@company.com
555555  Rachel Greene   rachelgreene@company.com    Torple Scott    torplescott@company.com
(How do you create/format tables on this site?) 
